# How to remove unwanted whitespace when filling listview with items (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms

Using c#, winforms.

**Background:**

The user should be able to select items from my menu strip, and then based on that the list view columns should be populated. Example: Select percent from 100-80 % then columns 1 and 2 get populated. Select total trans from <1000 and then column 3 and 4 get populated.

**Problem:**

When adding items to my listview, say I select option 1 from menu strip. Then columns 1 and 2 get filled up. Good. BUT right after if I select option from total trans, the column 3 and 4 do get filled up, BUT there is a ton of WHITEspace in the columns. Basically, the columns should not have white space when getting filled up.

This is what I mean: Notice the whitespace (outlined by red). First I selected option 1, then as soon as I selecte the option to populate column 3 and 4, they filled, but with whitespace. The column values for col 3 and 4 should have nothing above them in white.

[image]

Also here: I select another option from menu strip (for col 1 and 2) , *after selecting the option to fill column 3 and 4,* and more whitespace:

[image]

**Code:**

```
   // Fill Column 1 and 2 from option 1
   private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

              int totItems = Seq3.Count - 1;
              if (PercentPopTolerance1.Count - 1 > totItems) totItems = PercentPopTolerance1.Count - 1;

              for (int i = 0; i <= totItems; i++)
              {
                  ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                  string item1 = "";
                  string item2 = "";


                  if (Seq3.Count - 1 >= i) item1 = Seq3[i].ToString();
                  if (PercentPopTolerance1.Count - 1 >= i) item2 = PercentPopTolerance1[i].ToString();

                  lvi.SubItems.Add(item1);
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(item2);



                  listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
              }

          }

          // Percent tolerance from 80-60%
          // Fill Column 1 and 2 from option 2

          private void toolStripMenuItem3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

              ClearColumn("columnHeader5");

              int totItems = Seq4.Count - 1;
              if (PercentPopTolerance2.Count - 1 > totItems) totItems = PercentPopTolerance2.Count - 1;

              for (int i = 0; i <= totItems; i++)
              {
                  ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                  string item1 = "";
                  string item2 = "";


                  if (Seq4.Count - 1 >= i) item1 = Seq4[i].ToString();
                  if (PercentPopTolerance2.Count - 1 >= i) item2 = PercentPopTolerance2[i].ToString();

                  lvi.SubItems.Add(item1);
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(item2);



                  listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
              }
          }

 // Fill columns 3 and 4 from option in total trans menustrip
 // Total trans tolerance < 1000

          private void etcToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

              int totItems = YYMMt21.Count - 1;
              if (TotalTransIrregularitiest21.Count - 1 > totItems) totItems = TotalTransIrregularitiest21.Count - 1;

              for (int i = 0; i <= totItems; i++)
              {
                  ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                  string item1 = "";
                  string item2 = "";


                  if (YYMMt21.Count - 1 >= i) item1 = YYMMt21[i].ToString();
                  if (TotalTransIrregularitiest21.Count - 1 >= i) item2 = TotalTransIrregularitiest21[i].ToString();

                  // Skip first 2 columns
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(string.Empty);
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(string.Empty);

                  lvi.SubItems.Add(item1);
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(item2);



                  listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
              }
          }
```

***EDIT: Trying User suggestion:***

New problem arises: what is supposed to be in column 3 and 4 vertically now fills the listview from the first row horizontally:
[image]

My attempt:

```
   private void etcToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

              int totItems = YYMMt21.Count - 1;
              if (TotalTransIrregularitiest21.Count - 1 > totItems) totItems = TotalTransIrregularitiest21.Count - 1;

              for (int i = 0; i <= totItems; i++)
              {
                  ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                  string item1 = "";
                  string item2 = "";


                  if (YYMMt21.Count - 1 >= i) item1 = YYMMt21[i].ToString();
                  if (TotalTransIrregularitiest21.Count - 1 >= i) item2 = TotalTransIrregularitiest21[i].ToString();

                  // Skip first 2 columns
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(string.Empty);
                  lvi.SubItems.Add(string.Empty);


                  int rowToPopulate = 0;
                  int colToPopulate = 0;

                  if (rowToPopulate <= listView2.Items.Count - 1)
                  {
                      //Editing an existing row/ListViewItem
                      listView2.Items[rowToPopulate].SubItems.Insert(colToPopulate, new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() { Text = item1 });

                       // How would I also add item2?
                       // listView2.Items[rowToPopulate].SubItems.Insert(colToPopulate, new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() { Text = item2 });
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      //Adding a new row/ListViewItem
                     // ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                      lvi.SubItems.Add(item1);
                      lvi.SubItems.Add(item2);
                      //Add all the other Subitems as usual

                      listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
                  }



                  //listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternate `Items.Add` and `Items.SubItems.Insert`. Sample code:

```
string curItem = "curVal";    
int rowToPopulate = 0;
int colToPopulate = 0;

if (rowToPopulate <= listView2.Items.Count - 1)
{
    //Editing an existing row/ListViewItem
    listView2.Items[rowToPopulate].SubItems.Insert(colToPopulate, new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() { Text = curItem });
}
else
{
    //Adding a new row/ListViewItem
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    lvi.SubItems.Add(curItem);
    //Add all the other Subitems as usual

    listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

This code checks whether the row being analysed (`rowToPopulate`) has already been populated or not. If it hasn't been populated yet, you can use the code so far (under the `else statement`, including as many `SubItems` as columns by letting blank the ones for which no information is available). If this is the second time that you analyse this row (some columns have already been populated and some other ones were left blank), you take the given `ListViewItem`/row (`listView2.Items[rowToPopulate]`) and insert the new element in the `SubItem`/column you wish.

Comment: Hi, @varocarbas I tried your suggestion and implemented in the loop where I can iterate through each sequence of my list. However, now the listview populates the the column horizontally (This part had white space before). 
I'm sure it's a syntax issue. (Edited my post so you can view Issue).

Comment: @Newuser rowToPopulate and colToPopulate are variables which you have to adapt to your code. rowToPopulate is the current row you are adding and colToPopulate the given column/SubItem. In your code, rowToPopulate equals i.

Comment: @Newuser you would have to adapt the colToPopulate numbers to each function (bear in mind that start from zero, the column completely on the left hand side).

Comment: appreciate the help. If I get this straight, it will iterate through each row and column. Now, everywhere I see rowToPopulate, I replace it with 'i', and i create another for loop for the columns (say I make index called ' b'). Now I basically have 2 nested loops for loop for rows (inside this for loop for columns and inside this code). Now, do I replace every 'colToPopulate' with 'b'?

Comment: @Newuser No, you have to adapt it to your current code. In your current code, each toolStripMenuItem goes through all the rows (and then, yes, replace rowToPopulate with i and put the code inside the loop); but columns behave differently, for example: toolStripMenuItem2 deals just with columns 1 and 2; bear in mind that my code only accounts for one column/value. Adapt it to deal with two columns/values and hardcode the corresponding column values in each method. Do you get the idea/can you do it by your own?

Comment: @vacrocarbas Ok good to know the i part is correct. Exactly, the different methods are for different columns. But I still don't understand if I should make a second loop for the columns. How should I encorporate the columns in each tool strip method and replace that with colToPopulate variable.

Comment: @Newuser (I thought that after having helped you various times already (you changed the nick but I recognise the code :)), at least, you knew that my nick is varocarbas) I have written custom codes for your various times, always hoping you to learn to do things by your own. Now you have to do a minor modification (which I have explained exactly how should be done) and you are not able to do it... You are lucky: look at the answer, he has decided to write some code; perhaps this version is easier for you to understand. I am sorry but will not modify my answer further. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @varicarbas hey, no problem at all. I would be extremely frustrated if I was on your side. You've gone out of your way to help me numerous times and I can't thank you enough. I will try my best to learn now. My only problem is that I don't know any syntax, thats why it's hard for me to implement the concepts people tell me too. Appologies for the absolutely lacklust effort and wrong name call varocarbas.

Comment: @Newuser You seem to be a person with the ideas clear: when someone says "don't do that", you keep doing it (why respecting others?). When you get something almost perfect for you and a person motivating you to do things by your own (= just reading my comment above with detailed instructions), you ignore this option and choose something which will be much more difficult to be adapted (or better: you mark other answer but will use my code? Are you able to do that? Well... I don't care). You know a lot: you know how to never get a new code again as the ones you were using so far. Congrats.

Comment: The reason why I marked his answer is because I just opted to use his method as it was pretty clear, I wouldn't use your code and not give the answer credit, that's ridiculous.

Comment: @Newuser "you opted to use his method" do you know that his method does not allow to do what you where doing so far? It expects to add all the columns at the same time? What you were complaining about in this question? See... I have been involved in too many ridiculous discussions during the last days. You are free to do whatever you want; I have just told you the consequences on my future help (no more help). I do this pretty often (the banned people list is growing really big :)).

Comment: Actually why I marked his answer as correct is because he gave me the idea to use listview1.items.clear(); I just oped to use this (i.e clear all contents when selecting a new option - simply because I couldnt understand anything else lol).
No worries, you have every right to report me, my mistake.

Comment: @Newuser Don't like too much this kind of mark changes; but here is deserved as far as the other answer didn't fulfil what you want. In any case you are free to do whatever you want; sorry for my agressivity (am aggressive some times, but just talking); but as said... we don't seem to think similarly and so... happy learning and continue enjoying SO!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell on your code, you just keep adding more items on the events, supplying String.Empty for the columns you're trying to skip.  If you want the new values from the next event to appear on the same row as values already present, you'll have to update the already existing rows SubItems and supply which values are to go on which row.

Edit:  I accomplished what you're trying to do with the below sample.  This assumes that you know or can get the size of each list you're trying to add to each column.  You'll have to implement some null checking etc to make sure you're not referencing null cells in the lists.  Just expand on this sample and tailor it to your exact situation.

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

List<string> lList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Clear();
    addColumns();
    for (int i = 0; i < sList.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item1 = new ListViewItem(sList[i]);
        item1.SubItems.Add(String.Empty);
        listView1.Items.Add(item1);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Clear();
    addColumns();
    for (int i = 0; i < lList.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i < sList.Count())
        {
            var item2 = new ListViewItem(sList[i]);
            item2.SubItems.Add(lList[i]);
            listView1.Items.Add(item2);
        }
        else
        {
            var item3 = new ListViewItem(String.Empty);
            item3.SubItems.Add(lList[i]);
            listView1.Items.Add(item3);
        }
    }
}

private void addColumns()
{
    listView1.Columns.Add("Column 1", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Column 2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
}
```

Comment: I get that, I'm just saying he has to go back and change the blank values that he added instead of just adding new items with more blank values.

Comment: OK. This is what my answer is about. But I guess that the question here was how this can be done? You are highlighting what is more or less obvious (I didn't read your answer properly because the first line was enough to understand that this is not what the OP is after IMO). Anyway... I thought that it was highlighting-worthy.

Comment: Much better. This is not fulfilling the exact requirements of the OP at all; but as far as he decided to behave as a 10yo, there you have the mark. Next time, try to add some code since the start mainly when the OP does not have the ideas too clear. You are new and so here is my advice: answer consisting just in text, unless the question is theoretical are pretty unlike to be of interest to the OP. Writing generic code is OK, but following more or less what the OP wants and the OP wants to populate different columns in differents moments (after the row was added) and your code is far from this

Comment: @varocarbas it doesn't really matter to me, I got to learn about the ListView today, something I'd never used, which is why I come to this site anyway.

Comment: This is exactly the spirit! Brilliant! You will certain become a good programmer.